# What is that alien in Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

At the end of the recent T.A.H.I.T.I. episode,

> We see the serum used to save Skye being extracted from a dead blue alien that was cut in half.

Are there any indications in any of the Marvel comics who that alien is?

Comment: was that not one of the aliens from the Avengers film? or am I on the wrong episode

Comment: It didn't look the same as the Chitauri.

Comment: Looked to me kinda like Doctor Manhattan.. ;)

Comment: My initial guess was that it might be a Frost Giant. I'm sure it will be revealed in later episodes All you need to do for knowing it is to wait. :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

We finally have a confirmed answer:

> **The blue alien is a Kree.**

Directly from [Marvel](http://marvel.com/news/tv/23698/learn_the_identity_of_the_mysterious_alien_race_in_marvels_agents_of_shield.):

> With the next episode of “Marvel’s Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.” Tuesday, December 2, fans will finally learn the alien corpse was of Kree origin, the intergalactic empire seen in Marvel’s “Guardians of the Galaxy.”

Statements in that article and in [this TV Guide article](http://www.tvguide.com/News/Marvels-Agents-Alien-1089443.aspx) imply that there may be a more specific significance in the identity of the alien corpse.

Comment: Do any of them have telepathic abilities?  I have the feeling Coulson realized something very specific about his experience, and that was the reason he wanted to stop them from injecting Skye...

Comment: @izkata, Not traditionally, as far as I can know/can find. Zatoans have a sort of "empathic" mystical ability, but nothing that would be considered "telepathic".

Comment: Could be close enough.  I'm gonna bet that if it's one of these three, it's a Zatoan...

Comment: Great answer. :)

Comment: The quick glimpse of the body made me think it was a genetically altered clone of Phil!! Shocker-doo!! Glad to be wrong on that score.

Comment: Sif pretty clearly says "Mentadites", not Interdites...

Comment: @Izkata Keen transcribed for me from closed captions.

Comment: “An Interdite” — damn, B, that’s Yoda.

Comment: My money's on a Kree. Also, I'm thinking that Skye's mysterious origin is that she's one of the pink-skinned Kree hyrbrids. This would explain why she had such a different reaction to the Kree blood than Coulson did.

Comment: Oh for crying out loud, man... spoilers much!??!?!?

Comment: Well, considering next weeks Mid-Season Finale coincides with the DVD/BLUE-ray release of GotG, that particular race makes the most sense - then again we have to consider the source of the information: Raina is not always the most reliable person in the room and she herself admits she only heard the name in legends...

Comment: @BMWurm Regardless of whether Raina is correct or not, the fact that Marvel itself is posting an article saying that it's a Kree is fairly definitive unless something else comes along to contradict it.

Comment: Additionally, at this exact point in time, Raina has not said that the blue alien is a Kree - she's just mentioned that the Kree exist (which is why I have not updated the answer again yet).

Answer (score 0):

Kree makes the most sense, given the need at some point in the Marvel cinematic (and now television universe) to introduce Skrull. With Skrull come Kree. Great intro, IMHO.

This arc is far too valuable in Marvel comic worlds to not expose/use it on the big screen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kree-Skrull_War

It needs to be bubbled up first, though. Cue the cameo of a dead blue Kree.

All of this is of course a precursor to a Skrull-Kree war in Avengers 3 with Thanos seeking the Infinity Gems.

Speculative, sure... but with the Infinity series being one of the better Marvel outings in the last couple of years, why wouldn't they capitalize on the potential.

Comment: Thanks to Fox having the Fantastic Four license, Marvel doesn't fully own the Skrulls for film use.

Answer (score -3):

I thought it was part of red skull, and it was just in some blue preserving liquid. It has deep eye sockets like him, and lots of hard looking, bone like skin.